# Why by printing a list of nltk bigrams for the second time an empty list as a result?

Tags: python, list, nltk, n-gram, empty-list

By multiple printing of the list of bigrams I get an empty list. How is that possible? The variable is not changing...or is that maybe a special thing with bigrams?

```
sent = ['Python', 'is', 'fun']
bigrams = nltk.bigrams(sent)
print(list(bigrams))
print(list(bigrams))
```

The result:

```
[('Python', 'is'), ('is', 'fun')]
[]
```

If I do it in a separate cell in jupyter notebook, the result is still an empty list:

```
print(list(bigrams))
[]
```

Comment: Perhaps `bigrams` a generator, which is used up (run to the end) after the first print? What is the result of `type(bigrams)`?

Comment: Do `bigrams=list(bigrams)`, then you can print it as many times as you want.